# Laravel Validator return json

Tags: php, laravel

same as title, i want to get message of validator in file javascript.

in file Controller:

```
public function processTest()
    {
        if (Request::ajax() && Request::method()==='POST') {

            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
                'firstname' => 'required',
                'lastname' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email|max:50|unique:tbl_account',
            ));

            return $validator->messages()->toJson();

        } else {
            return Redirect::route('home');
        }
    }
```

in file dev.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test-form').submit(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

but not working, it result empty, somebody can help me????

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
 return  Response::json($validator->messages());
```